# How to stop something having a co-efficient of restitution over one

Tags: physics, materials

A team scientists working in a laboratory situated at the now disused ISS (We are talking about 2577) has ultimately discovered exotic matter however it is nothing like we have ever seen before in fact it seems to break the very laws of physics. Made from exotic subatomic particles which constitute the very fabric of space time this material has novel properties in its physical state.

One of the properties I wish to really include is to make it *violate* the law of conservation of energy by giving it a co-efficient of restitution which is greater that one. But the problem is how to store such a material effectively and also what other quirky properties I can give it. It would be better if the properties would *violate* something that has been established truth like I use the the co-efficient of restitution to violate conservation of energy.

Note: I don't care if it violates laws of known physics it is an exotic material and is supposed to do so

Comment: If this thing was floating around in an atmosphere, wouldn't it just collide with gas particles until it reached c?

Comment: You can give it whatever properties got want... Once you decided your story breaks fundamental physic law, knowledge we have is useless. Just don't let it bounce.

Comment: May be useless to you, but I am thinking that such material can produce enough heat for a nuclear fusion plant.

Comment: @suhridmulay Could you describe the co-efficient of restitution in laymans terms (for those of us who aren't physicists), it would help greatly in other users understanding the question and subsequent answers.

Comment: The ISS orbits rather low, and its orbit [decays](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orbital_decay) naturally, mostly due to atmospheric drag. If it was left alone, it would burn up in Earth's atmosphere within a decade, so its orbital altitude is regularly boosted using rocket engines. Since an uncontrolled re-entry of something that size would be dangerous, it will be deorbited in a controlled manner when it isn't wanted any more. It's quite implausible that it would have been kept into the late 2500s.

Comment: Seems like idea generation to me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Congratulations, you have invented **[Flubber](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Absent-Minded_Professor)**

So essentially you have something that generates energy out of thin air, literally so even as air molecules that bump into this bounce away at a higher velocity.

The practical upshot of this is that it heats up things. Any kind of fluid — be it liquid or gas — that you put this material into will heat up over time.

So the simple way to store this is in **water**. The water will heat up. You simply need to pump the water through some kind of cooling-system, or just attach heat sinks to the side of your container to vent away the excess heat that your substance generates.

In fact this is not far removed from being like a [Radioisotope Thermoelectric Generator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radioisotope_thermoelectric_generator), minus the electricity and the ionizing radiation.

[image]
*An RTG with its distinctive heat sinks that vent away heat generated by the radioactive isotopes*

As for quirky qualities... well, you are free to make up whatever you want here. But the obvious one is that it makes Oobleck and other Non-Newtonian fluids look kind of amateurish. For inspiration, check out the movie(s) linked in the headline: *The Absent-Minded Professor*.

Answer (score 1):

One approach might be to have it only violate the laws of physics in some situations.  To appease the perpetual energy community of today, maybe it only violates the conservation of energy when exposed to a powerful magnetic field.  They'd love that, and it would give you an on/off switch for this peculiar property.  This might be comparable to how currently known superconductors only superconduct at low temperatures.  Heat them up, and the effect vanishes.

Of course, you're going to have a beast of a time with [Nother's Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Noether%27s_theorem), so minimizing how much time people spend on your material that violates conservation of energy is desirable.  Don't put too much detail into it!